# Error with Cassandra Authenticator (Cannot achieve consistency level QUORUM)

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I get an error with cassandra Authenticator.
cqlsh return me this error after I changed the value "authenticator" in cassandra.yaml file:

```
Connection error: (‘Unable to connect to any servers’, {’127.0.0.1’: AuthenticationFailed(‘Failed to authenticate to 127.0.0.1: Error from server: code=0100 [Bad credentials] message=“org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.UnavailableException: Cannot achieve consistency level QUORUM’“)})
```

here is the command I ran step by step:

```
sudo apt-get install cassandra

cqlsh

ALTER KEYBASE system_auth with REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy',
‘dc1’: 3 }*// dans cqlsh

//replace AllowAllAuthenticator by PasswordAuthenticator in cassandra.yaml

sudo service cassandra restart

cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra

Connection error: (‘Unable to connect to any servers’, {’127.0.0.1’: AuthenticationFailed(‘Failed to authenticate to 127.0.0.1: Error from server: code=0100 [Bad credentials] message=“org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.UnavailableException: Cannot achieve consistency level QUORUM’“)})
```

I follow this part [Configuration authentication](https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/2.2/cassandra/configuration/secureConfigNativeAuth.html)

here is my configuration:

[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra3.0.9 | CQL spec 3.4.0 | Native protocol v4]
Ubuntu 16.04.1

Any ideas ?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a 1 node cluster and a replication factor of 3 in a DC you cannot achieve quorum consistency (over half of 3 is 2 but theres only 1 node). System auth requires quorum so change your RF to 1. Also possible your nodes are not actually in "dc1" so there is no replicas. Include your `nodetool status` and it will help identify how many nodes in each DC.

Comment: perfect, my node was in datacenter1. problems solved, Thanks !